# I need to take a string of names add each name to a list and then print with index number

Tags: python-3.x

```
names = "Jack Jill Mary Bob"
nameslist = []
counter = 0
if len(names) >= 1 :
    space_pos = names.find(" ")
    name_list[counter] = names[0:space_pos]
    names = names[space_pos:]
    counter = counter + 1
else:
    def print_list (x):
        for i in range(0, len(x)):
            print (x[i])
        return x
    print (print_list(name_list))
```

So I have been set a task for homework but I am really struggling with it. (I Have only been coding python since September!) This is how far I have got but i keep getting errors.
The task was:
Write the steps to take the string of names and to add each name to a list as separate elements of a list.

Code your solution, the solution should display the list with the list index number
e.g.
0 Jack
1 Jill
2 Bob

Comment: What happened to Mary in your example?

Comment: How are you learning python if you are "coding" python since September? Are you supposed to avoid the [split method](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split)? The `for i in range(0, len(x))` thing is as unpythonic as it gets. What is your question?

Comment: You put the first name in the list.  You need a loop to process more than one name.  Your code does not define, nor call, `print_list` when you have names, only when you have an empty string.

Comment: The define part was from a python code academy task we did.

Comment: the only code we were given was:    space_pos = names.find(" ")
    name_list[counter] = names[0:space_pos]
    names = names[space_pos:]
    counter = counter + 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add each name to a list by using split(). The code simplifies very much.

```
names = "Jack Jill Mary Bob"
counter = 0

name_list = names.split() #This splits the names variable and turns them into list items
for item in name_list: # For each item in name_list
    print(counter, item)

    counter = counter + 1
```

Comment: Oh thats how split works! I found it on another question but didn't know if you could apply it to this circumstance. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
names = "Jack Jill Mary Bob"
nameslist = names.split()
for i in range(len(nameslist)):
    print(i, nameslist[i])
```

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Posted over 2 months ago when I didn't know the rules very well...got downvoted for it once and learned my lesson...what's your excuse? ;)

Comment: Extra comment on when obvious what you are doing , I think that it is unnecessary.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY I know, right?! That was my argument too when I was downvoted, but it didnt fly...had to edit and eventually delete the answer. Apparently, there's still a class of creatures called "beginners" :)

Comment: You will should have a belief. The person's intention does not depend on downvotes. If you say that it's necessary to explain, you should edit this answer.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY First of all, the code here is not nearly as complicated as yours. The language here is python which reads like pseudocode, everything here is basic; there are no comments to be added. Your code is in C and uses pointers, which usually confuses things. I also find it weird that you're still going on about this; you have 28k rep, and you've been here for four years, you should know better; going by our conversation here, your English is good enough that you can add a few comments to your code to explain what happens.

Comment: Ridiculous talk.  _Posted over 2 months ago when I didn't know the rules very well_

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112101/discussion-between-tisteandii-and-bluepixy).